# Zoom option if highcharts is working randomly

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, zooming, disable

I am having highcharts where when I select a date "All" option in highcharts id disabled
For the date range below 2020-01-01 and 2020-03-04

finally, the option "YTD" and ALL will be enabled as shown below

after when YTD is clicked in zoom option ALL is disabled

this I am not able to understand what is happening can anybody please explain this behavior

Breaking my head for days on this know please help

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on? Here is a template which you can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-7d1nd

Comment: can u please why YTD option is not coming in the demo

Comment: I had a problem with codesandbox, please check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-iwrbff?file=components%2FStock.jsx

Comment: In the same example on load just click on YTD All will be disable please let me know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YTD** - means year to date. It shows a date from one year period. You can better see how it works here: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

---

EDIT:

In the React demo which I shared (stackblitz.com/edit/react-iwrbff?file=components%2FStock.jsx) the `YTD` disables `All` button because, as I described above, the YTD shows a one year period date, so in this demo, it shows the whole data ('All') - it's like two buttons have been clicked in one time, so the implemented logic blocks one. It works totally different in the official demo which I shared - please test it to understand.